# Creating a cross account IAM Lambda role using CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

In my scenario I have 2 accounts (11111111, 22222222) that need to+ invoke a lambda in a 3rd account: 33333333. The lambdas in the 3rd account will be invoked from lambdas in the first 2.

The lambdas in 3rd account are created on the fly but I need to give them a role which I wish to create using CDK (which I will do using 3rd account creds - no cross account stuff here).

I am following the instructions [here](https://blog.e-sainc.com/blog/2018-04-17/lambda-cross-acct-access/) - invoking the lambda using STS seems straightforward. What I am not fully clear on is how to define the 3rd account role in cdk.

Here's my stack:

```
export class ModuleIAMStack extends Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props)

    const lambdaModuleRole = new Role(this, 'moduleRole', {
      roleName: 'moduleRole',
      assumedBy: new AccountPrincipal({ accountId: '111111111' }),
      managedPolicies: [ManagedPolicy.fromAwsManagedPolicyName('service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole')] // My lambdas in 3X... will not need to access any resources so this should be enough to execute
    })
  }
}
```

I am unclear on the `assumedBy` line. Is `AccountPrincipal` the correct entry? and if so how do I enter the 22222222 account?

Comment: "What I am not fully clear on is how to define the 3rd account role in cdk" - are you expecting to create a role in the 3rd account by executing the cdk code in one of the others? If so I doubt that's possible, unless within your 3rd account you've already granted your other accounts access to all the necessary resources. We do x-account stuff between multiple accounts but we already have roles defined in the various accounts and permissions allowing those roles to be assumed by the account that does x-account stuff. Took a quick look at the link and it seems to be the same as we do.

Comment: No I will be creating the role in the 3rd account using cdk and 3rd account creds. No problem there. It's more on how to define the role in 3rd account whose ARN I will use in account 1/2 to invoke the 3rd account lambdas. Mainly I am unclear if `assumedBy` is correct - how can I use that for 2 accounts? Im a bit vague on this part of IAM in general.

Comment: I've never used cdk but from the docs it seems `AccountPrincipal` is for a singular account, whereas with CF/sam templates (which we use) the corresponding property takes an array of account numbers to apply this to (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_principal.html). Perhaps it's a limitation of cdk?

Comment: Or, see this bug logged some time ago (seemingly now fixed) which shows usage of that class with multiple account ids: https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/924

Comment: For anyone coming here and trying to follow the blog post linked in the question, here is a blog post very similar to that one, but using CDK: https://faun.pub/cross-account-access-to-invoke-aws-lambda-using-aws-cdk-2e925e6f9e56

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`AccountPrincipal` will generate a principal like this: `arn:aws:iam::123456789012:root`. This is enough to allow the whole account.

And as for the CDK - you are almost there:

```
assumedBy: new iam.CompositePrincipal(
    new iam.AccountPrincipal('111111111'),
    new iam.AccountPrincipal('22222222')
),
```

Comment: How to resolve if I want to use a user alongwith the AccountPrincipal ?

Comment: @Judi You should probably ask a new question rather than adding a comment.

Comment: does this mean "give access to accounts 1 and 2"?

Comment: @GeoffLangenderfer Yes, that's correct.